# find the gradient of a function with 3 variables with one of them being a function of the other 2

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

given a function $F:R^{3}\rightarrow R,$ such that $F(x,y,2x^{2}+y^{2})=3x-5y,$
define $u(x,y)=2x^{2}+y^{2}$

find the gardient at the point (1,2,6).

i am also given that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(1,2,6)+2\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(1,2,6)+2\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(1,2,6)=\sqrt{5}.$

my solution: define $g:R^{2}\rightarrow R,g(x,y)=F(x,y,u(x,y)),$whice
means $g(x,y)=3x-5y.$

there for: $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(1,2,6)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(1,2,6)\cdot1+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(1,2,6)\cdot0+\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(1,2,6)\cdot\frac{du}{dx}(1,2,6)$.

the RHS euqlas $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(1,2,6)+4\cdot\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(1,2,6)$
while the LHS is $3$. so i get:

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(1,2,6)+4\cdot\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(1,2,6)=3$

and then i can do similarly for $y$ and get 3 equations with 3 variables?
is the eqation i got here correct?

Comment: How did you conclude from $F(x,y,\color{red}{2}\,x^2+y^2)=3x-5y$ and $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ that $F(x,y,u(x,y))=3x-5y\,?$ Besides : The gradient of $F:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ is -as we know- the vector of partial derivatives of the *three* independent variables $x,y,z\,.$ Your function has only two independent variables $x,y$. So it is unclear what the question exactly is.

Comment: There was a typo in the definition of u. F has 3 variables but we dont have a general expression for the function. we do have enough information to find the gradient at this point from the assumptions. This was a question i got on a test.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$
v(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\u(x,y)\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
We know from the chain rule that
$$\tag{1}
\nabla (F\circ v)=J^\top(v)\,\nabla F  
$$
where $J^\top(v)$ is the transpose Jacobian of $v\,:$
$$
J^\top(v)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \partial_x u\\ 0 & 1 & \partial_y u\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 4x\\ 0 & 1 & 2y\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$

The LHS of (1) is
$$
\nabla (3x-5y)=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-5\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Therefore the gradient of $F$ must satisfy
\begin{align}
3&=\partial_xF+4\,x\,\partial_zF\\[2mm]
-5&=\partial_yF+2\,y\,\partial_zF\,.
\end{align}
At $(1,2,6)$ this is
\begin{align}
3&=\partial_xF+4\,\partial_zF\\[2mm]
-5&=\partial_yF+4\,\partial_zF\,.
\end{align}
The other equation you are given I write as
$$
\partial_x F+2\,\partial_y\,F+2\,\partial_z F=\sqrt{5}\,,\quad (x,y,z)=(1,2,6)\,.
$$
You did not solve the three equations with the three unknowns $\partial_xF,\partial_yF,\partial_zF$ that we have now.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: We did not learn this method but i see you got the same result as i  did, so this helps, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another method which is not so rigorous and may get downvotes:

Let $F(x,y,z)=3x-5y+\phi(z-2x^2-y^2).$ Then, at $(1,2,6)$ we have:

$F_x=3-4\phi'(0)$
$F_y=-5-4\phi'(0)$
$F_z=\phi'(0).$

From the given equation $F_x+2F_y+2F_z=\sqrt5$, we find $\phi'(0)=-\frac{7+\sqrt5}{10}$ and
$$\nabla F=F_x+F_y+F_z=-2-7\phi'(0)=\frac{29+7\sqrt5}{10}.$$